# Why does Indesign combine my csv columns into a single entry, when data merging?

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

I'm data merging a csv file into a indesign file to export buisness cards. However when I select the csv for data merging, Indesign reads the file and should display the columns in the file as seperat entries, but instead it combines them into one:

[image: screenshot of indesign data merge read error]

The data should show up as individual entries for

- Name
- Rolle
- Telefon
- Email

Alas, not combined like in the screenshot.

---

The csv file is set up like this:

[image: screenshot of csv file layout in excel]

for obvious reasons I can't show the data, but there is 25 rows of data below, set up the same way as the sample data here.

Some data-fields contain the danish special-characters æ, ø and å (if that could play a role?).

Comment: Thank you! Could you post your comment as an answer? Then I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV is comma-separated values. On some windows machines (when win is not English) the comma is changed with semi-colon. And in the result csv files are exported with ";" in place of ",".
 You can change it in windows regional settings or just save file as Tabbed Text.

Answer (score 2):

No it's because InDesign looks for commas as a separator while Excel will use a semi-colon. Prefer Tabbed Text as export format. InDesign will like this better ;)